# Is a std::string implementation conformant where 's.c_str() + s.size()' is not necessarily the same as '&s[s.size()]'?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, language-lawyer

`§21.4.5 [string.access]`

```
const_reference operator[](size_type pos) const;
reference operator[](size_type pos);
```

> *Returns:* `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`. Otherwise, returns a reference to an object of type `charT` with value `charT()`, where modifying the object leads to undefined behavior.

The second part implies, to me atleast, that this "object of type `charT`" may reside outside of the sequence stored in the `std::string` object. Example implementation of a conforming `operator[]`:

```
reference operator[](size_type pos){
  static contexpr charT default = charT();
  if(pos == size())
    return default;
  return buf[pos];
}
```

Now, `c_str()`/`data()`, are specified in terms of `operator[]`:

`§21.4.7 [string.accessors]`

```
const charT* c_str() const noexcept;
const charT* data() const noexcept;
```

> *Returns:* A pointer `p` such that `p + i == &operator[](i)` for each `i` in `[0,size()]`.

This would make the above `operator[]` implementation non-conformant, as `p + size() != &operator[](size())`. However, with a bit of trickery, you can circumvent this problem:

```
reference operator[](size_type pos){
  static contexpr charT default = charT();
  if(pos == size() && !evil_context) // assume 'volatile bool evil_context;'
    return default;
  return buf[pos];
}

struct evil_context_guard{
  volatile bool& ctx;
  evil_context_guard(volatile bool& b)
    : ctx(b) {}
  ~evil_context_guard(){ b = false; }
};

const charT* c_str() const noexcept{
  evil_context_guard g(evil_context = true);
  // now, during the call to 'c_str()', the requirement above holds
  // 'p + i == &operator[](i) for each i in [0,size()]'
  const charT* p = &buf[0];
  assert(p+size() == &operator[](size()));
  return p;
}
```

Now, the obvious question is...

**Is the above code *really* conformant or did I overlook something?**

Comment: One thing I notice is that if you were actually write the check out for a string object `str`: `char* p = str.c_str(); size_t i = str.size(); assert(p + i == &str[i]);` the assertion will fail with your code. The standard doesn't seem to specify a specific context where the invariant must hold, so I'd be careful about assuming it only needs to hold before `c_str()` returns.

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the given code, considering only the question, I think that

- unfortunately, the answer seems to be “yes”, and
- that is certainly not the *intent* of the standard.

Hence, it appears to be a **defect**.

Checking the [list of known library defects](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-index.html#Section%2021) apparently this issue has not yet been reported.

So, as I stated in chat, I recommend posting it to [comp.std.c++], in order to get resolved the question of whether it *really* is a defect, and if so, to get it into the defects list and fixed.

Comment: I have a vague suspicion that this is intentional. This wording allows for empty strings to be represented using a single `static char` somewhere (without this wording, the null byte would have to be unique to every string, which would require either (1) empty strings being represented using an in-object null-byte, or (2) requiring a dynamically allocated buffer). I'm not sure why this would be preferable over (1), but it seems an odd coincidence that this wording makes it possible, so I suspect it's intentional

Comment: @jalf: SSO is all about have small strings without dynamic memory allocation. It would be perfect for this null byte so I don't see how it would be an issue. Would you mind explaining ?

Comment: @ildjarn: No, obviously not, but it does demonstrate that there is no reason for null string not to be able to allocate an in-class null character.

Comment: @Matthieu : It also doesn't disprove that the standard may be allowing for implementations that don't provide SSO and would benefit from a static sentinel value, so I'm not sure what your point is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how it could be conformant. User code can never observe the promised returned value. The `assert` in the code is misleading because it is in the wrong place: the function has not returned yet. *Returns:* requirements apply to be value returned from the function, not to some value within its implementation (it should be obvious why that is a nonsensical idea).

The assertion should be here:

```
auto p = s.c_str();
assert(p + s.size() == &operator[](s.size()));
```

I believe the wording that treats `s[s.size()]` specially is simply meant to forbid you from blowing up the null terminator.

Comment: To stop me from blowing up the null-terminator, they could've just said "don't modify the value referenced by `s[s.size()]`" and wouldn't need to allow this specific value to exist outside of the sequence.